# constructing call stack as shown by gdb

Tags: operating-system, gdb

I want to understand how to build a call stack as gdb does on running backtrace command. This was asked in an interview and I answered it based on my knowledge of call stack and stack frames. I think this is done using the stack pointer, the return address/instruction of the caller and mapping it to the executable / assembly instructions. I have been looking for how it is actually done or a good explanation of this stack walk. All the information I found on googling was related to microsoft API to this walk programmatically and I am looking for a generic explanation of how to approach building a call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google search led me [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Consider the very simple `ix86` calling convention with frame pointers. Every time you call a routine, the address of the next instruction is pushed onto the stack. Called routine immediately upon entry executes `push %ebp; mov %esp,%ebp` instructions. You then end up exactly with the layout from the page above.

Let's say you are stopped in routine `foo`, called from `bar`, called from `baz`, called from `main`.

You examine two words pointed to by `%ebp`. The first word is the previous value of `%ebp` (let's call it `prev_ebp`, the second is the return address -- instruction pointer somewhere inside `bar`.

You now examine two words pointed to by `prev_ebp`. The first one will be `prev_prev_ebp`, the second will be a return address -- instruction pointer somewhere inside `baz`.

Repeat until you reach main, and you have executed roughly the procedure that GDB uses.

There are many practical complications, such as frames that don't use frame pointer, but you are not expected to understand that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it's done in gdb, but here's an idea, If you could keep all the `jmp/call` instructions and their target addresses in a stack, then at any point you would have a full call trace.